# javascript new Date() or moment.js parse date wrong

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I have a DateTime value that comes from server in the following format:

```
2015-08-16T01:29:00.000Z
```

However when I do

```
new Date('2015-08-16T01:29:00.000Z')
```

the result is this:

```
Sun Aug 16 2015 04:29:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)
```

please notice the hour is wrong, instead of `01:29 AM is 04:29 AM`

Same for moment.js it get's the wrong hour.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the same time -- the server gives it to you as UTC (hence the `Z` at the end) and Javascript then helpfully shows it in the local timezone of the browser, FLE Daylight Time. Given that both times clearly state which timezone they are, nothing is going wrong, strictly speaking.

What to do depends on what you want exactly. By doing

```
moment.utc('2015-08-16T01:29:00.000Z');
```

You put moment.js in UTC mode, showing everything in UTC (if I understand the docs correctly).

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you!